# TNS error ORA-12154 Using Symfony DoctrineBundle

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine, dbal

I'm getting TNS Error (ORA-12154). From the log file, this is the error we get.

> app.ERROR: error while trying to collect executed migrations {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException(code: 12154): An exception occurred while executing a query: An exception occurred in the driver: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at /../vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/OCI/ExceptionConverter.php:66)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException(code: 12154): An exception occurred in the driver: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at /../vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/OCI/ExceptionConverter.php:66)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Exception\ConnectionFailed(code: 12154): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at /../vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/OCI8/Exception/ConnectionFailed.php:24)"} []

For some reason, it happens randomly.

Environment:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.3
- Symfony 5.3 (with DoctrineBundle for OracleDB connection)
- (with enough cpu and memory)

What we tried so far are the ff:

1. To update the "config/packages/doctrine.yaml" and set directly the oracle dbname and servicename. this fix seems to work before. But after a few days the same TNS error happens again.
2. Prepare test PHP script (not using Symfony/doctrine dbal) for testing purposes, but use the same oci_connect and same tnsnames.ora used by the framework. From testing, we do not encounter a TNS error (ORA-12154).

What we suspect is, that this could be related to environment variables that cannot be properly fetched. As I mention above, when we put dbname to doctrine.yaml before, this somehow fix our problem.  Just not sure why it happens again.

Comment: There’s going to be a mix of things going on, so for clarity: the error message means that the connecting string specified cannot be resolved to a full address via your tnsnames file. Tnsnames is default located in the Oracle home but you may also have a tns_admin environment variable set or it is in the same directory as the calling program (unclear which program would be chosen here but this setup is uncommon).

Comment: for tnsnames.ora we define the TNS_ADMIN in the index page via
putenv("TNS_ADMIN=/directory/network/admin").

it works with this setup, but for some reason sometimes not

Comment: The overall recommendation for Oracle is to set environment variables _before_ the process starts, not in the app.  This is precisely because users see inconsistencies like the one you see.  Yes there are occasions when it's OK to use putenv() but ...  don't do it. See the section "Setting the Oracle Environment" in the [user doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) which has a big warning against putenv().

Comment: Hi Cristopher, thanks for your input. We tried the recommendation from php oci8 documentation. to remove the putenv() and set only via apache (SetEnv). But still we are getting ORA-12154 from time to time. Not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: We also have upgraded versions of our PHP to 7.4, Symfony to 5.4, and Oracle Client to 21.6. still we get the same error.